# Active Directory userAccountcontrol multiple values in a filter

Tags: filter, active-directory

What is wrong with this filter?

```
(&(objectClass=user)(&(userAccountControl=512)(userAccountControl=514))(|(sfrecordtype=10)(sfrecordtype=30)(sfrecordtype=32)(sfrecordtype=35)))
```

It works fine with only one `userAccountControl` value. How can I create a working filter with both 512 and 514 for `userAccountControl`?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is wrong with this filter?*

Well, your `userAccountControl` value **CANNOT** be 512 **AND** 514 at the same time - that's what your filter is requesting. This will **never** be the case....

You want to combine the values 512 and 514 with an **OR** condition - **either** `userAccountControl = 512` **OR** `userAccountControl = 514` - try this:

```
(&
    (objectClass=user)
    (|(userAccountControl=512)(userAccountControl=514))
    (|(sfrecordtype=10)(sfrecordtype=30)(sfrecordtype=32)(sfrecordtype=35))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to search for these specific values. You probably want to check the specific bits you're interested in instead. The reason is that the search would not include any user that has other UAC flags set, which is a very real possibility.

You would do that using a bitwise OR search:

```
bitmask = 512 | 514; // technically just 514 works

...(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=bitmask)...
```

This would return any user that matches the `‭001000000010‬` mask.